# Cannot create ECC certificate in apple developer account

Tags: ios, cryptography, certificate, apple-push-notifications, keychain

Trying to create apple developers push certificate for ECC algorithm as communication with APNS required ES256 alg as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1).

> NOTE: APNs supports only provider authentication tokens that are
>   signed with the ES256 algorithm. Unsecured JWTs, or JWTs signed with
>   other algorithms, are rejected, and your provider receives the
>   InvalidProviderToken (403) response.

Getting error below,

> CSR algorithm/size incorrect. Expected: RSA(2048)

[image]

**Any idea why?**

Note: I have created proper ECC based signingcert from Keychain app.

Comment: See this answer on a related question with the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117146/670028

Answer (score 1):

I have changed stripe csr file extension from stripe.certSigningRequest to stripe.csr and Its working fine for me.